# how to send email in java?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email in this code but every time it is showing  username and password not accepted.
but I have done everything. I have also set my gmail account to access third party apps. Now I don't understand where is the problem is.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d8sm6051763pfd.159 - gsmtp
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.mirajhossain.TransMail.sendMail(Main.java:37)
    at com.mirajhossain.Main.main(Main.java:52)][1]
```

Here is my code.

```
class TransMail{
        public static void sendMail(String recepient) throws MessagingException {
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.from","REDACTED");
            properties.put(" mail.user","REDACTED");
            properties.put(" mail.passr","REDACTED");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port","587");

            String myAccount="miraj98hossain@gmail.com";
            String pwd="69miraj69hossain69shawon69";






            Session session= Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(myAccount,pwd);
                }
            });

            Message message= preparemessage(session,myAccount,recepient);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("yes");
        }

    private static Message preparemessage(Session session, String myAccount,String recepient) throws MessagingException {
            Message message=new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myAccount));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(recepient));
            message.setSubject("Verification");
            message.setText("1254562");
            return message;
    }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        TransMail.sendMail("miraj09hossain@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you won't want to put your actual email/password in questions.

Comment: Past questions may help answer this quickly https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+mail+gmail+smtp

Comment: i have seen their code and tried those too but still showing AuthenticationFailedException   username and password not accepted.

Comment: Sorry,Code is running well now.It was my email who was blocking.i have turned on the less secure app in setting.it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to turn on less secure app access from your gmail account settings.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "test@gmail.com";
        String pass ="xxxxxxx";
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "test313@gmail.com";

        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        // Setup mail server
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        int Vcode=(int)(10000+Math.random()*(20000-10000+1));

        try{
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Email Verification");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("Your verification code for our app is"+Vcode+".\n"+"Enter this code for complete your sign up process");

            // Send message
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using JavaMail library. Look how it looks:

Configure:

```
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        mailSender.setHost(host); // for example smtp.gmail.com
        mailSender.setPort(port); // 465
        mailSender.setUsername(username); // your email
        mailSender.setPassword(password); // your password

        Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol); // smtps
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", debug); // as you wish
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", auth); // true 
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", enable); // true 

    }
```

Send message:

```
private void send(String subject, String message) {
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        mailMessage.setFrom(emailFrom);
        mailMessage.setTo(emailTo); // receiver
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(message);

        mailSender.send(mailMessage);

    }
```

Try this.

Comment: i tried your code but it shows a exception     [Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for protocol. Failed messages: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for protocol; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for protocol]

Comment: Because your low and dont understand what to do? Problem is not in code, but in your understanding @Miraj Hossain Shawon